# ReadList and multiple access of the same file

Tags: data

I have a file containing a large amount of data which can be processed independently. In order to process all data in a reasonable amount of time I distribute the jobs on three different machines. Each job accesses the data file via the command `ReadList`.

My question is, if there may be a problem accessing the data file from three programs at once. Thanks in advance, I very much appreciate any help.

Comment: `ReadList` works with Streams. You can do :`str=OpenRead[filename]; ...=ReadList[str]; Close[str]`